# Unable to wget/curl the zipped file on remote server

Tags: linux, download, zip, wget

I've been trying solution similar to my case but none solved my problem. I have zip file on remote server, but when I download it using wget or curl, it keeps returning 404. To make sure that I have zip file on the server i run

```
[rootname@server]$ file my_file.zip
```

returning

```
Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

but whenever I wget/curl the zipped file it gives

```
Connecting to my.remote.server... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

How can I download the zip file correctly?

Comment: It might be worth [edit]ing the question to include an example of the curl command you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.
**file** command, doesn't confirm that this file is on the web server,
so actually this file is not on your server (404).
If you try with your own web server, then make sure you put it to right directory...